# System Argument exception parameter is not valid while trying to display a bitmap

Tags: c#, image, serialization, memorystream

Have been trying various options to display a rectangular face capture in a picture box, have been trying for a few days but feel I got close with this code

```
//preparing FaceRecord
fr.FacePosition = new FSDK.TFacePosition();
fr.FacialFeatures = new FSDK.TPoint[FSDK.FSDK_FACIAL_FEATURE_COUNT];
fr.Template = new byte[FSDK.TemplateSize];
fr.image = new FSDK.CImage();

fr.image = fr.image.CopyRect((int)(fr.FacePosition.xc - Math.Round(fr.FacePosition.w * 0.5)), (int)(fr.FacePosition.yc - Math.Round(fr.FacePosition.w * 0.5)), (int)(fr.FacePosition.xc + Math.Round(fr.FacePosition.w * 0.5)), (int)(fr.FacePosition.yc + Math.Round(fr.FacePosition.w * 0.5)));

Car car = new Car();
car.Name = "Temp";                   

MemoryStream stream = Serializer.SerializeToStream(car);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Temp.Jpeg", stream.ToArray());

using (var Stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Temp.Jpeg")))
{
    Car cab = (Car)Serializer.DeserializeFromStream(Stream);
    var imageToSave = Bitmap.FromStream(Stream);

    pictureBox2.Height = imageToSave.Height;
    pictureBox2.Width = imageToSave.Width;
    pictureBox2.Image = imageToSave;
 }
```

The parameter not valid exception is just above in the

```
Var imageToSave = Bitmap.FromStream(Stream);
```

Can anyone give me any advice as where to go next?

Serializer code

```
public class Serializer
    {

        public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream;
        }

        public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }
    }

[Serializable]
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name;                       
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your serializer code?

Comment: The bitmap constructor will throw an `ArgumentException` if the stream you pass it doesn't contain a known image format, and you aren't serializing out an image, you're only serializing an object of type `Car`. How can you load an image if there's no image to load?

Comment: @theB am a PHP programmer trying my hand at C#, understand and respect your comment, just finding this one a hard one to get my head around

Comment: Apologies jackofnotrades if that came across as hostile, I was trying (and apparently failing) to ask a question that may have lead you to your answer. @jdweng's answer below points out more clearly what I was trying to get at.

Comment: @theB as said respect your comment, from your comment thought I may of found my mistake, jdweng then confirmed it, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things wrong.  1) There was no image in the Car Class only a name.  Then Bitmap.FromStream was using the entire Car class to get image where you need to ignore name and just use the image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            Car car = new Car();
            car.image = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\image1.jpg");
            car.Name = "Temp";
            MemoryStream stream = Serializer.SerializeToStream(car);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Temp.Jpeg", stream.ToArray());

            using (var Stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Temp.Jpeg")))
            {
                Car cab = (Car)Serializer.DeserializeFromStream(Stream);
                var imageToSave = Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream( cab.image));

            }
        }
    }
    public class Serializer
    {

        public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
            return stream;
        }

        public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: after reading your post and seeing it correctly I assume from my code I has trying to load an Object and not an image, thanks m8